# Haskell function does not terminate

Tags: haskell, terminate

I´ve written a function in Haskell that takes three points in the plane,
and checks if they´re on a straight line, or make a right or left turn.

Here´s the code:

```
detDirection :: Point -> Point -> Point -> Direction

detDirection a@(Point (x1, y1)) b@(Point (x2, y2)) c

= if (collinear1 a b c)
     then Straight
     else let
            ab                  = Vector [x2 - x1, y2 - y1]
            angleAbX            = angle ab (Vector [1, 0])
            (Point (x1, y1))    = turnAtP a b angleAbX
            (Point (x2, y2))    = turnAtP a c angleAbX

          in if (y1 > y2)
               then Right
               else Left
```

I´ve tested `collinear1`, `angle`, `turnAtP` in GHCi, and they all terminate immediately.
`detDirection`, however, keeps running forever.

Can someone tell me where the problem here is?

Comment: Tried stepping through it line-by-line?

Comment: Turn warnings on (`:set -Wall` in GHCi) and you'll get some clear indications of what you did wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Haskell, `let` is a recursive binding, that is, you can refer to variables declared in the `let` expression in the defining expressions of the other variables. So, when you write

```
let
        ab                  = Vector [x2 - x1, y2 - y1]
        angleAbX            = angle ab (Vector [1, 0])
        (Point (x1, y1))    = turnAtP a b angleAbX
        (Point (x2, y2))    = turnAtP a c angleAbX
```

the `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` on the first line do not refer to the function arguments but to the same names declared later on in the `let` expression. Just change the two `Point` lines to bind some different variables, like

```
        (Point (x3, y3))    = turnAtP a b angleAbX
        (Point (x4, y4))    = turnAtP a c angleAbX
```

and modify your later computation accordingly, and your infinite looping will go away.

Comment: Thank you very much,
I can´t believe I actually shadowed my function arguments without noticing.....
Next time I´ll use the warnings in GHCi!